# Trying to get nginx proxy to work on port 80 and 443 for node.js with docker

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

So I am trying to follow the example [here](https://blog.ssdnodes.com/blog/tutorial-extending-docker-nginx-host-multiple-websites-ssl/) to do a nginx proxy container that will handle all other containers. I have tried following the format that configure the environment variables so that the sites work through the nginx-proxy. So far I have only gotten a site deployedif I use a port other than my 80 or 443. I was wondering I could get any help regarding this I have pasted two of my files below.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:carbon                                                                                                      
# Create app directory
WORKDIR ./home/username/website/production

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"                                                                                                          
    services:
        website:
            build: .
            volumes:
                - .:/home/user/website
                - ./home/user/website/node_modules
            ports:
                - "8080:8080"
            expose:
                - 80
            environment:
                VIRTUAL_HOST: domain.com
                LETSENCRYPT_HOST: domain.com
                LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: domain.com
    networks:
        default:
            external:
                name: nginx-proxy
```

I have tried listening on ports 80 and 443. However, nginx returns an a 503 error. So I was wondering if anyone could shed some light on how this is supposed to be configured.

Comment: Does it work on port 8080? I don't see anything in your `docker-compose.yml` file mapping 80 or 443 to port 8080, which is what your node app is listening on

Comment: Also, are you serving with node? On which port is your app listening? You need to map 443/80 to that port

Comment: I serve on port 80 right now as so app.listen(80), and when I've gotten it to work with port 8080 I add the port line to the docker-compose file. I am actually thinking of just trying it through normal docker like it is on the GitHub of the docker container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it to deploy two separate containers one as domain.com and the other as subdomain.domain.com with both listening on port 80. The site even defaults to https like expected as nginx handles that. Rather than use the docker-compose.yml file, I redid the nginx-proxy following the instructions of the [github page](https://github.com/JrCs/docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion) rather than the blog using normal docker. After that I deployed using their format as follows:

```
docker run --detach \
    --name your-proxyed-app
    --env "VIRTUAL_HOST=subdomain.yourdomain.tld" \
    --env "LETSENCRYPT_HOST=subdomain.yourdomain.tld" \
    --env "LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=mail@yourdomain.tld" \
    nginx
```

These are found on their [wiki here.](https://github.com/JrCs/docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion/wiki/Basic-usage#step-3---proxyed-containers) I think I will avoid docker-compose for now at least until I learn more about docker itself, but if anyone could shed some light as to why the docker-compose setup didn't work, it would be appreciated.